# Ajax file upload more than one input and some data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I want to upload files that contain `3` inputs and more than `4` variables.

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <form id="upload_files" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
    <input type="file" name="fileName1" form="upload_files"><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileName2" form="upload_files"><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="fileName3" form="upload_files"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next" id="next_button" form="upload_files">
</body>
```

**Jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#next_button").on("click", function(){

            // Some Variables
            step = 1;
            file1 = 1;
            file2 = 2;
            file3 = 3;

            /*ajax code*/

        }); // end next button

    });
```

**EDIT :**
Thank you for your answers. I tried the [krishnapal dhakad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9766811/krishnapal-dhakad) code and worked only when i added an `e.preventDefault();`**(Is there a way to work say without preventDefault (); ?)**. The disadvantage is that I also wanted to send variables, so I tried with the hidden input of [Dharmendrasinh Chudasama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7346931/dharmendrasinh-chudasama) and i didn't figure out how to call it in php, I'd put `$ _POST` and `$ _REQUEST`, did not work. While I tried [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045034/8746125) the `data.append ("step" , 1);` where I can call it with `$ _POST` or `$ _REQUEST` and it worked fine. [Dharmendrasinh Chudasama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7346931/dharmendrasinh-chudasama) this way with `$ .ajaxSubmit();` seemed to me somewhat complicated for me, if you could give me more information about this I would be very thankful.

Thanks for your time,
Andrew.

**EDIT Jquery :**

```js
$("#next_button").on("click", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $("#upload_files")[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);

    //Taking this variable on php with $_POST or $_REQUEST
    data.append("step", 1);
    data.append("file1", 1);
    data.append("file2", 2);
    data.append("file3", 3);
    data.append("max", 1);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "upload.php",
      data: data,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });// end ajax

});// end next button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following javascript code to submit form.

```
var form = $("#formId")[0];
var data = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "form-submit-url",
  data: data,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden field in that form, and then you can directly submit form by ajax using `$.ajaxSubmit()` but for that you should use plugins like **jquery** and **jquery-form**